# I have a reference and want to call a function that takes boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, reference, shared-ptr

I have a reference to an object and want to call a function that takes a boost::shared_ptr of this object. If I build a boost::shared_ptr to make the call when my boost::shared_ptr is canceled from the stack than the object is canceled too! This is exactly what happens when I run this code:

```
double f(boost::shared_ptr<Obj>& object)
{
  ...
}

double g(Obj& object)
{
  boost::shared_ptr<Obj> p(&object);
  double x = f(p);
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to make it work? How can I create in g() a boost::shared pointer that leaves my object alive at the end? I think I have to connect it to the reference counting machinery of other shared pointers that already point to object... but how?

Even if I make it work do you think this way of doing is bad design? What is the best practice to solve this kind of problems? In my code I have objects and methods that work both with shared pointer and references and I cannot work only with these or those...

Comment: Why does the function take a shared_ptr?

Comment: Function f() is a method of an object that contains a persistent map of properties of Obj objects. These properties are stored in a map that links shared pointers to the properties. The shared pointer is needed to look for the object in the map. I would say that function f() has to work with shared pointers because it partecipates to the ownership of the Obj objects.

Comment: @martino Why does the map use `shared_ptr<Obj>`, and not just `Obj` (in which case, `g` would take a `Obj const&`, and not a `shared_ptr<Obj>`).

Comment: Have you considered making a copy of the object? i.e. `f(boost::shared_ptr<Obj>(new Obj(object))` -- Or do you need it to reference the same object?

Comment: @James What do you mean by a map where the keys are the Obj? Should the key be raw pointers to Obj?

Comment: &Benjamin Yes the idea is not to duplicate the objects both because I have maps that use their pointers and to save memory.

Comment: Not raw pointers (although in some cases that might be appropriate), but objects themselves.  There are exceptions, but you generally don't want pointers in maps, smart or otherwise.

Comment: @martino And how much memory are you saving?  `std::map` is pretty gluttony when it comes to memory to begin with.  The difference between using a pointer and using a value is generally not going to be significant.

Comment: @James: it's a question of whether the properties really are associated with an already-existing object (but can't be stored in it for some reason, such as that the class cannot be modified). If so then the map key must be the address of the object. Alternatively, perhaps the properties are associated with a value of the type `Obj`, in which case obviously you're absolutely correct, the map key ideally is `Obj`, not any kind of pointer to Obj. So the test is: can two objects have the same value, but have different properties? If not, then use `Obj` as the key.

Comment: @SteveJessop If the properties are associates with already-existing immutable objects, whose existence is guaranteed for the lifetime of the `map`, then pointers may be appropriate.  Another reason which forces using pointers is inheritance---any time the objects are polymorphic, you must use pointers, whether you like it or not.  Otherwise... I'd go with using the object.  (Except maybe in extreme cases: 5 or 6 maps whose index is a `Matrix2D<1000, 1000>`, and all of the maps have the same keys.  But I doubt such cases are common.)

Answer (score 8):

A function that takes a `shared_ptr` is saying something about what it does. It is saying, "I want to potentially claim shared ownership of this object". If this is not true, then it is a poorly written function and shouldn't be taking a `shared_ptr` at all.

A function which takes a value by non-`const` reference to an object means that the function can modify the object, but *cannot* claim ownership. If you don't own something, you also can't give ownership to someone else.

Now, you could perform this trick of using an empty deleter function:

```
void EmptyDeleter(Obj *) {}

double g(Obj& object)
{
  boost::shared_ptr<Obj> p(&object, EmptyDeleter);
  double x = f(p);
  ...
}
```

However, you are now *lying* to `f`. It doesn't own `object`; it *can't* own `object`. It is very possible that `object` is a stack object that may disappear any time after `f` completes. If `f` were a member of a class, it might store the `shared_ptr` in a member variable. At which point, it would then have a `shared_ptr` to a *dead object*. This is exactly the sort of thing that `shared_ptr`s are intended to prevent.

The correct answer is for either `f` to not take its argument by `shared_ptr` (use non-`const` reference or non-`const` pointer if it is modifiable, and `const&` if it is not modifiable), or for `g` to take its argument by `shared_ptr`.

Comment: +1 for "the correct answer" paragraph. Tricking the function is not the right solution here.

Answer (score 4):

You may create a `shared_ptr` that doesn't actually free the object. Like this:

```
struct FictiveDisposer {
    template <class T> void operator ()(T) {}
};

Obj& object = /* ... */;
boost::shared_ptr<Obj> myPtr(&obj, FictiveDisposer ());

// you may use myPtr
```

However you should use this carefully. If you're sure the function you're calling won't try to "save" your object for later use - there's no problem. Otherwise you **must** guarantee that the lifetime of the saved `shared_ptr` to your object won't exceed the actual lifetime of your object.

In simple words: you got the reference to the object. You didn't create it, and you may not affect its lifetime (neither `shared_ptr` can). Hence there may happen a situation where the object doesn't exist anymore, still it's referenced by `shared_ptr`. This must be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You must consider the purpose of f(). Presumably if it takes a shared_ptr, f intends to retain shared ownership of this pointer over time, past its return. Why? What is f() assuming when you pass it a shared_ptr? Once you answer this question you will be able to figure out how to code g().

If for some reason f() does not need to retain shared ownership of the pointer, then if you have control over its interface it could be rewritten to take a Obj* or Obj& instead of a shared_ptr. Any code possessing a shared_ptr could then call f by pulling the pointer out of the shared_ptr or dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create in g() a boost::shared pointer that leaves my object alive at the end?

You can give the shared pointer a custom destructor that does nothing:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Obj> p(&object, [](void*){});
```

or if your compiler doesn't support lambdas:

```
void do_nothing(void*) {}
boost::shared_ptr<Obj> p(&object, do_nothing);
```

> Even if I make it work do you think this way of doing is bad design?

Yes: you lose the lifetime management that shared pointers give you, and it is now your responsibility to make sure that the object outlives all of the shared pointers.

> What is the best practice to solve this kind of problems?

Decide on an ownership model for all the objects you're using, and stick to it. Shared pointers can be useful when you want to share ownership, but not otherwise. In your case `f` wants to share ownership, and whatever calls `g` seems to want exclusive ownership; it would be a good idea to think about why they want that, and whether you can change one to be compatible with the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a sign of poor design for a library interface to take a
`shared_ptr` (but there are exceptions).  Since the function you're
calling expects to take responsibility, or at least partial
responsibility, for the object you pass it, and the rest of the code
isn't prepared for this, you're only safe solution is to clone the
object, e.g.:

```
double x = f( boost::shared_ptr<Obj>( new Obj( object ) ) );
```

But you'd really be best off finding out why `f` requires a
`shared_ptr`, and why `g` can't take one as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

`std::shared_ptr<T>` is to possible give multiple entities ownership of the referenced object. If an interface expects a `std::shared_ptr<T>` there are two possibilities:

1. Someone ignorantly used `std::shared_ptr<T>` in an interface which was meant to receive a `T` object or a reference or a pointer to a `T` object. If that is the case the author shall be educated (and if this doesn't work be released from his current duties to pursue a new career) and the interface corrected.
2. Since now all interfaces using a `std::shared_ptr<T>` are using this to possibly grant shared ownership to the object, it should be obvious that a stack allocated `T` isn't a suitable argument to such an interface. The only possible argument is a `T` object whose life-time is maintained vy a `std::shared_ptr<T>`.

I realize that this doesn't answer the original question but it should be clear that the only viable course of action is: **don't** ever try to pass an object to a function taking a `std::shared_ptr<T>` which can't be fully controlled by such a pointer! (the same applies to the `boost` version of shared pointers).